# What could be the solution for "Entity Type has no key defined" error except for adding [Key] or naming variable as ID or EntityNameId?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am getting an error

> Entity Type has no key defined

while trying to scaffold. I have tried all the solutions including adding `[Key]` and naming the variable `ID` or `EntityNameID`. However, no single solution worked out for me.

This is what I have done so far:

`Movie` class:

```
namespace MvcMovie.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
       [Key]
       public int MovieId { get; set; }
       public String Name { get; set; }
       public DateTime publishDate { get; set; }

       public virtual ICollection<Play> Plays { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`Actor` class:

```
namespace MvcMovie.Models
{
   public class Actor
   {
       public int ActorId { get; set; }

       public String First_Name { get; set; }
       public String Last_Name { get; set; }
       public DateTime Date_Of_Birth { get; set; }

       public virtual ICollection<Play> Plays { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`Play` class:

```
namespace MvcMovie.Models
{
   public class Play
   {
       public int PlayID { get; set; }
       public int ActorID { get; set; }
       public int MovieID { get; set; }
       public int Pay { get; set; }

       public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }
       public virtual Actor Actor { get; set; }
   }
}
```

`DbContext`:

```
namespace MvcMovie.DAL_Data_Access_Layer_
{
   public class MovieContext: DbContext
   {
       public MovieContext() : base("MovieContext")
       {
           this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
       }

       public DbSet<Models.Actor> Actors { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Models.Play> Plays { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Models.Movie> Movies { get; set; }

       //protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       //{
       //    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
       //}
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to generate your entities from an existing database?

Comment: No, I am trying to make my own models.

Comment: Instead of naming them ID or EntityID, try naming them `Id` in `Movie` and `Actor` and name them `MovieId` and `ActorId` in `Play`(and rename `PlayId` to `Id` as well).  This should allow EF to do its "magic."

Comment: Ah, because scaffolding is telling EF to generate the code from the database, it's confusing to use that word :)

Comment: I still get the same error. I just tried.

Comment: Do you have any other entities in your DbContext?  Are you certain the error is coming from one of these three?

Comment: No, I do not have any other entities in the DbContext and The error is coming from Movie.

Comment: What is the script of your three models ? provide the DB script also .

Comment: I just did, you can check now.

Comment: @Learner, I mean go to your DataBase here is SQL Server management and right click on your table in your table database explorer then `Script Table as => Create To => New Query Editor Window` and paste that scripts here.

Comment: I don't why, but there are none created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know there is no problem with your models and connections between them is right,
but you said in comment there is no created DB and tables, right?  if yes so you should learn about migration from [Here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/migration-in-code-first.aspx)

anyway if you want to know what `script` will be created by your model design try to execute below migration code:

```
public class Configuration<T> : DbMigrationsConfiguration<T> where T : DbContext
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }
}
public class DbMigrations
{
    public static void UpdateDatabaseSchema<T>(string SQLScriptPath = "C:\\script.sql") where T : DbContext
    {
        var configuration = new Configuration<T>();
        var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
        SaveToFile(SQLScriptPath, dbMigrator);
        dbMigrator.Update();
    }

    private static void SaveToFile(string SQLScriptPath, DbMigrator dbMigrator)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SQLScriptPath)) return; 
        var scriptor = new MigratorScriptingDecorator(dbMigrator);
        var script = scriptor.ScriptUpdate(sourceMigration: null, targetMigration: null);
        File.WriteAllText(SQLScriptPath, script);
        Console.WriteLine(script);
    }
}
```

by executing that migration in `application start` like :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DbMigrations.UpdateDatabaseSchema<Models>();
}
```

you will see the generated `script` in `SaveToFile` method located in `C:\\script.sql` is like :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Actors] (
    [ActorId] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [First_Name] [nvarchar](max),
    [Last_Name] [nvarchar](max),
    [Date_Of_Birth] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Actors] PRIMARY KEY ([ActorId])
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Plays] (
    [PlayID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [ActorID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MovieID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Pay] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Plays] PRIMARY KEY ([PlayID])
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Movies] (
    [MovieId] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max),
    [publishDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Movies] PRIMARY KEY ([MovieId])
)
CREATE INDEX [IX_ActorID] ON [dbo].[Plays]([ActorID])
CREATE INDEX [IX_MovieID] ON [dbo].[Plays]([MovieID])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Plays] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Plays_dbo.Actors_ActorID] FOREIGN KEY ([ActorID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Actors] ([ActorId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Plays] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Plays_dbo.Movies_MovieID] FOREIGN KEY ([MovieID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Movies] ([MovieId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

there is no any problems by testing below snipped code:

```
Models model = new Models();
var actor = new Actor
{
    Date_Of_Birth = DateTime.Now,
    First_Name = "first name",
    Last_Name = "last name"
}; 
var movie = new Movie
{
    publishDate = DateTime.Now,
    Name = "movieN"
};
model.Movies.Add(movie);
model.SaveChanges();

//adding new relation 
var foundAct = model.Actors.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ActorId == 1);
foundAct.Plays.Add(new Play
{
    ActorID = foundAct.ActorId,
    MovieID = 2// MovieId from Db
}); 
model.SaveChanges();
```

Make sure your migration works and tables are in DB or execute that script in your Database if you don't want to have migration.

Answer (score 0):

You must define a public key for each entity called id. Plus, you need to define a foreign key to you other entities.

```
 [ForeignKey("Movie")]
 public int id { get; set; }
```

(inside of Play class for example).